# Chrome Hangs when launching Angular App with VS Code

Tags: angular, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, vscode-debugger

I have an Angular 7 CLI app that makes chrome hang when I try to debug it using Chrome(76) and VS Code(1.37). I can't even open up the debugging tools and inspect index.html but I run `ng serve` just fine. I can even open up http://localhost:4200/#/ in an existing chrome and firefox tab and the page loads but when I try to launch chrome from VS Code to debug nothing gets loaded into the browser.

I have tried a couple different configs for launch.json and they have the same results

Out of the box config

```
    {
  "name": "ng serve",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:4200/#",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

Advanced config: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Angular-CLI

```
{
  "name": "ng serve",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
  "url": "http://localhost:4200/#",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
    "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
    "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
    "/*": "*",
    "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
  }
},
```

I have tried a couple of other things without success:

- Reinstall chrome
- Install VS Code 1.36
- Install Vs Code Insiders
- I restart my windows machine.
- Clone a fresh copy of my repo, running npm install and rebuilding the application

So I created a new empty Angular CLI application `ng new` and I am able to debug it just fine. Which leads me to believe it isn't related to chrome or vs code. Then I decided to give firefox debugging a try and it works just fine but now I am really confused.

```
    {
  "type": "firefox",
  "request": "launch",
  "reAttach": true,
  "name": "Launch Firefox localhost",
  "url": "http://localhost:4200/#",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was security related issue with my developer machine. I was able to get around the issue by using a different chromium based browser(Opera, Edge Beta, Brave).

[image]

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/911

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Calidus answer, go to launch.json and just change "Chrome" to "Edge"

```json
{
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Edge against localhost",
      "type": "edge",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },...
```